# Using DRY principle in Laravel Blade Template

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-blade, code-injection

Am trying to use DRY approach in my Blade templates. How do i reuse @section instead of copying them to several templates.

Example:

```
@section('job_level_menu')
   @foreach ($job_levels as $job_level)
   <option value="{{{$job_level->id}}}">{{{$job_level->name}}}</option>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

I wish to use this section in many other templates and i don't wish to copy them for code maintainability

Secondly, I have several Repositories that is common to all my controllers. Is  it possible to inject a repository in BaseController __construct() method which will be available in other controllers.

i tried this but its not working:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @param MenuRepositoryInterface $menu
     */
    public function __construct(MenuRepositoryInterface $menu){

        $this->menu = $menu;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save this section in separate file and in files you need it you can use:

```
@include('file_with_section')
```